# facebook graph api: /links for different friend

Tags: facebook-graph-api

when I try to get all the links for some of my friend I get an empty data result.
I have a full access token, maybe this limitation is due from the friend's permissions? There is some workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to get all the links for some of my friend I get an empty data result. I have a full access token, maybe this limitation is due from the friend's permissions?

You would need `read_stream` permission from the friend – and the friend would have to give it to you yourself, meaning he would have to be a user of your app and must have granted that permission themselves. And you would need to have an active user access token of the friend stored somewhere.

> There is some workaround?

If you would be satisfied with getting all the links of a friend your current user is allowed to see, then you could filter the [FQL `stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) with your user’s id (or `me()`) as `source_id`, your friend’s id as `actor_id` and `type=80` (for type *Link posted*).

(And with that, you could also do it for *all* friend’s links in one go, using a “sub-query” on the friends table for the `actor_id`.)

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get the same empty array with SELECT action_links,post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND actor_id=(friend id) AND type=80 what's wrong?

I'm sure this friend have links and I can see it.

Comment: And also, why this read_stream it's not needed for every friend, there is a way to check if I need this permission or if the user have 0 posts of that type? thanks