# FQL: privileges to see a friend's posts

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm trying to get all the posts of a friend with FQL, for some friend, I can retreive all the data needed but with someone other, I get an empty object as response, this is the query:
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=friendID

Knowing that I can actually see the friendID's posts through facebook, I tryed, to get the data through the api, adding a field in whitch use my id as id of the user who is asking for the data

SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=friendID AND viewer_id=me()

I also tried this method, advised to me by another user:

SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE actor_id=friendID AND source_id=me()

None of what i tried works, so, my questions are:

-This friend should grant me access to his data through the api? And how?
-There is an hack to bypass this problem?
-There is a way to understand if the user have 0 posts or I can't see his posts?

Thank you

Comment: have you already requested the user access token with needed permission read stream ? because it seems that you got the info you want from some of your friends? Also have already created an application in Facebook? just to check before giving an answer

Comment: I have full permission for my access token.
I have my api but sometimes i use the api explorer to check if the problem is linked to the app or is more general
from two other question I understand:

-I can't see X(a friend) posts (also with complete access token) from graph api because of his privacy settings OR because his non-permissions to my app or because he have no posts. [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16770964/check-permission-to-see-friends-content)

Comment: -(this seems to don't work)I could filter the FQL stream table with your user’s id (or me()) as source_id, your friend’s id as actor_id and type=80 (for type Link posted) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752197/facebook-graph-api-links-for-different-friend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that your friend is not allowing apps to bring his info while you can see those data through your facebook account.

Why?
Go to **Account Settings** then go to **Apps settings** then select the option **Apps other use**.
just click here to directly open those settings https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view

You will see a list of categories and most of them are checked (See image below)... so if your friend unchecked the options that he doesn't want apps to access then you will not be able to access the info using an app while, as I said before, you can see these info from your Facebook account.

[image: Apps other use settings]

There is no solution for this because it's a privacy setting your friend prefer...
**Note:** if your friend added your app then app permissions will override the categories that don't permit the access of apps then queries will return info.

You can check it yourself. Create a temp facebook account and try changing those options and query the stream of your temp account with your main FB account. you will figure it out...